# How do I use grep to count the number of occurrences of a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I use grep to count the number of occurrences of a string?

input:

```
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
```

```
// a.txt
aaa
```

```
// b.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Now I want to know how many times `aaa` and `bbb` appear.

output:

```
aaa: 2
bbb: 1
```

Comment: If a string appears multiple times in the same file do you want to know how many times, or does that just count as `1`?

Comment: If a string occurs multiple times on the same *line* of a file, do each count separately? Is that a relevant possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:

```
grep -E "aaa|bbb|ccc" *.txt | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

This means:

```
grep -E "...|..." : extended grep, look for all entries

The result is given as:
a.txt:aaa
b.txt:aaa
b.txt:bbb
b.txt:ccc

awk -F: '{print $2}' : split the result in 2 columns, 
                       based on the semicolon, 
                       and only show the second column

sort | uniq -c : sort and count unique entries
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `awk`. This uses `split` to count the occurrences of the search patterns and puts them in the "associative" array `n`.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ pat1="aaa"; pat2="bbb" } 
    { n[pat1]+=(split($0,arr,pat1)-1) } 
    { n[pat2]+=(split($0,arr,pat2)-1) } 
    END{ for(i in n){ print i":",n[i] } }' a.txt b.txt
aaa: 10
bbb: 14
```

##### Example data

```
$ cat a.txt
aaa
aaa efwepom dq
bbb qwpdo bbb
qwdo qwdpomaaa
qwo bbb
pefaaaomaaaewe bb aa
aaa bbb

$ cat b.txt
aaa
aaa efwepom dq
bbb qwpdo bbb
qwdo qwdpomaaa
qwo bbb
pebbb bbb fobbbmebbbwe bb aa
aaa bbb
bbbbbbsad
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `grep` is if you have more than one item on a single line.
`grep` counts *lines*, so you need `-o` and another instance of `grep` or a `wc` or some such.

```
$: cat lst
aaa
bbb

$: cat a.txt
aaa

$: cat b.txt # I added a second hit on the bbb line
aaa
bbb bbb
ccc

$: files=( [ab].txt )
$: time while read pattern; do 
     printf "%s: " "$pattern";
     grep -o "$pattern" "${files[@]}" | wc -l;
   done < lst
aaa: 2
bbb: 2
```

Note that this is slow, even with such a small dataset.

```
real    0m1.119s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.308s
```

This lets you make a list file, but reads every file in your target set once per pattern, and executes the `grep` AND the `wc` on each. [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9462095/andre-wildberg)'s `awk` solution would be cleaner, faster, and generally better all around, especially if you put the list in a file and parsed against that rather than as a set of literals.

```
$: time awk 'NR==FNR{ pats[$0]; next; } 
   { for (p in pats) { n[p]+=(split($0,arr,p)-1) } } 
   END{ for(p in n){ print p": ",n[p] } }' lst "${files[@]}"
aaa:  2
bbb:  2
```

Considerably faster - likely MUCH more so on more data and files.

```
real    0m0.344s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.092s
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of occurrences of 'aaa' and 'bbb'

```
hi$ echo 'aaa: '$(grep 'aaa' <<< paste a.txt b.txt | wc -l);echo 'bbb: '$(grep 'bbb' <<< paste a.txt b.txt | wc -l);

aaa: 2
bbb: 1
```

In general:

```
#!/bin/bash
#delicious coconut recipe
#mmm!

mmm="aaa","bbb","$1";coconut=0;
IFS="," read -ra More <<< $mmm;
for delicious in ${More[*]};
do

echo "$delicious: "$(grep ${More[$coconut]} <<< paste a.txt b.txt | wc -l);

coconut=$(( $coconut + 1 ));
done;
```

This was enough for me:

```
regId='1680790311';filename="../imported/userdb.tmp";
```

First, I get the line identifier (regId) and extract the second part (-f2) of its first division level (-d'_'). Against this second level, I grep it to match its inner delimiter (-d'#'). Finally, with wc, I count the number of occurrences. It gives me a number (n = 'wc number') of grouped people talking (n+1) about a topic related to some item of the first level.

```
grep "$regId" $filename | cut -d'_' -f2 | grep -o "#" | wc -l
```

Thanks to Paul Hodges (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70380712/revisions).